# Present modelview controller not returns the value from NSObject class?

Tags: ios, nsobject

I m using NSObject class for implementing the facebook share, but my app get crashed when i click share button because present modelview controller not supported to return the value,  please help me out.

This is my code:

`[self presentViewController:facebookPostVC animated:YES completion:Nil];`

Comment: You Have to create a custom view controller class for doing this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class should be inherited from UIViewController and you should have a View , which will be presented by another view , otherwise , how can an object be presented ?

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html